# How do I concatenate a string with a value returned from a mule expression?

Tags: mule, mule-el

I am trying something like the following to concatenate a string and a value returned from a mule expression

```
 <message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="Set value as SessionVar">
        <add-message-property key="someKeyName" value="'Key ' + #[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['value']]"/>
  </message-properties-transformer>
```

I've tried other variations, as well, without luck.  I'll happily post variations, if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and use: `#['Key ' + message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['value']]`